# Android Studio Error: Adb refused a command

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I just changed my PC, and now I have a problem with Android Studio, every time i try to run or compile an app it install it correctly, but then it cannot start the main activity of the app, if you need it this is the full Android studio output:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_i9000-3733E37B1ACB00EC
Uploading file
local path:   C:\Users\Federico\swagmasta\TurnarioConapo1.0\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/feddycapdev.conapo.turnario
Installing feddycapdev.conapo.turnario
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/feddycapdev.conapo.turnario"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/feddycapdev.conapo.turnario


Launching application: feddycapdev.conapo.turnario/feddycapdev.conapo.turnario.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "feddycapdev.conapo.turnario/feddycapdev.conapo.turnario.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error: Adb refused a command
```

I tried to manually run `am start -D -n "feddycapdev.conapo.turnario/feddycapdev.conapo.turnario.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` from the adb shell, and it work correctly, some ideas on how could i fix it?

**UPDATE** : I tried running as admin, rebooting PC, reconnecting cable, killing all the adb.exe processes, killing the adb server and restarting it, noone of this worked.
Maybe it's a problem of driver? I'm using a Samsung Galaxy S for debugging, at the beginning the PC didn't recognized it, so I installed samsung USB driver, so maybe that's the real problem, but if i can install app to my device via adb the driver should be working right?

Comment: Have you tried launching Android Studio as admin?

Comment: Is this happening after reconnecting cable by disconnecting once?

Comment: I always run all as admin since i use the Administrator account, and yes, i tried to reconnect the cable, and even to reboot, the nonsense thing is that the command for launching the activity work in the adb shell but doesen't work in Android studio...
Is it possible that it's a driver problem? I installed samsung USB driver right before starting android studio, so maybe that's the real problem, but if i can install app to my device via adb the driver should be working right?

Answer (score 3):

Please kill and start adb server from console or terminal using following commands:

```
adb kill-server 
adb start-server
```

If it does not help try to restart your computer.

If you are getting

> adb command not found

error then you have to go in platform-tools directory in Android SDK.

hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

It could be blocked by some other instance of adb.

Look into your task manager if you are not running another instance of adb.